# Problem with cp bash command: path not recognized

Tags: bash

I try to copy a files from my desktop (windows) to a remote server (linux) via ssh
I connected shh and try the command:
scp /Users/jl3.PRT-063/Desktop/test.txt /home/zebra/scripts/

and got the error:
cp: impossible d'évaluer '/Users/jl3.PRT-063/Desktop/test.txt': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

problem of path?
I verify my 2 paths (origin and destination) using chdir and pwd and tey are good

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: not sure to understand what you say... path C:/Users/jl3.PRT-063/Desktop/test.txt is the correct path

Comment: my local desktop is Windows and I try to copy from my local to rmeote linux server

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/592445

Comment: I see no host part in the scp  command that you provided.

Comment: @alecxs: I look at link but don't have any explainations ;

Comment: @Yuri: /Users/jl3.PRT-063/Desktop/test.txt is the local path

Comment: Use `export LC_ALL=C` to generate English error messages.

Comment: no such file or directory error

Comment: If there is no host part in both arguments then you are copying files locally.

Answer (score 0):

scp test.csv user@194.168.80.9:/home/user/scripts/

problems comes from the fact I tryed to send files from PuTTy server connexion!!!